# SQLite Select query not returning desired value from table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, logcat

I have created a **database helper class in which I have written a select query** like this:

```
//select statement
        public String select(String question_id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 


        String sql = "SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE _id="+question_id;
         Log.i("select: ",sql);

        db.close();
        return sql;

}
```

This is how I am **calling the select method from an activity**:

```
//select statement to retrive previous answer from database
                DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(ExamActivity.this);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                try {
                 db.createDataBase();
                 chk_content = db.select(question_sr_no.getText().toString()); 

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
                db.close();
```

But the **logcat** output is:

```
SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE _id=1.
```

**Why is query not returning the result, instead returning the query string?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you are printing this Log.i("select: ",sql);

Comment: You need to run the query!

Comment: Where are you firing the query? You will have to use something like db.rawquery() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to execute query using `db.rawQuery`. Change your method as :

```
public String select(String question_id) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
   String str_answer="";
   String sql = "SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE _id="+question_id;
   Log.i("select: ",sql);
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null); //<< execute here 
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
      str_answer=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answer");
    }
  return str_answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only Logging, you're not calling the [query method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29).

Answer (score 0):

Your select method just creates a string and returns the string. Take a look in your own code.

```
 //select statement
    public String select(String question_id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

    String sql = "SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE _id="+question_id; //you return this. 
     Log.i("select: ",sql);

    db.close();
    return sql;

}
```

I guess what you are after would be to actually query the database, not just open it and close it again.